# Get data from another application in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-manifest

I have two application app1 and app2 installed.
And i want to launch an activity of app2 from app1. And then come back to the activity on app1 with some data from app2. But i am able to return back to app1 , but not able to get the data.

from app1 :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sampleText);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.app2","com.example.app2.MainActivity"));     
        startActivity(intent);
```

from app2:

```
Intent goBack = new Intent();
        goBack.putExtra("result","asdaf");
        setResult(RESULT_OK, goBack);
        finish();
```

manifest of app1:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

manifest of app2:

```
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />                
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />               
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />    
            </intent-filter>
```

I am not getting a hit on function in app1.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {                                 
          if (requestCode == 1) {

             if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
                 String result=data.getStringExtra("result");                   
                TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                tv.setText(result);
             }
             if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {    
                 //Write your code if there's no result
             }
          }
        }
```

What am i missing here?. Is there any settings need to be done for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using startActivityForResult in "app1":

```
startActivityForResult(intent, SOME_CONSTANT);
```

The constant you pass will be passed back as the requestCode argument.  So in your case it looks like you would want to pass in 1.

See the docs for more info: [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)